# How to include an anchor tag in a Feature description

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, feature

Is there a way to include an anchor tag in the description of a feature; my reason for this is to take the user to a page that has the configuration instructions for the feature.

Currently what is displayed when I add an anchor tag to the description is

<a href="/_layouts/somepage.aspx"> linky </a>

so the html is being encoded, is there a work around of alternative I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried to inject it programmatically into the description field and it printed out encoded. There for with a OOTB field this is not possible it seems, the only way I can see is to make a new custom field if you want it to be done perfectly OR there is a javascript solution (Quick and dirty):

Add the link as a marker ie #linkstart #linkend in the description and use JQuery to replace these markers after page load with the correct tags. (Which is by far the simplest solution)

Answer (score 0):

> I think it is possible, you can try it using JavaScript, something
>   like this

```
<a name="#Chapter1">Chapter 1</a>
```

and then click event as

```
<a onclick="javascript:this.href='#Chapter1';" href="javascript:;">Chapter 1</a>
```

but you can also try another solution

Edit your publishing page and select some text. Now click “Insert/Link/From Address”. In the pop up window just type “/” for the “Address” field. Remove “/” from the URL field and add “#Chapter1” or equivalent value to “Bookmark”. Now you will be able to create an anchor to “#Chapter1”. Just select some other text in your page. Now click “Insert/Link/From Address”. In the pop up window just type “#Chapter1” for “Address”. Save and your inpage link will work.

Reference : [anchor-links-tags-in-sharepoint-2010](http://yalla.itgroove.net/2012/05/anchor-links-tags-in-sharepoint-2010/)

Comment: I did see your post but it looks geared towards pages rather than feature description per se

Comment: since feature description comes within XML tag, maybe this link help you :) 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604452/embed-an-html-anchor-in-an-xml-doc

Comment: That looked really promising, I thought it was going to work but alas no, it just writes the whole statement to the screen <![CDATA[ and everything.